# nmap scanning Raspbian with strange results

Tags: nmap, ports, raspberry-pi

I'm a high schooler in a CyberDefense Class and we are learning to PenTest.

I'm on Red Team and my teacher set up a system with Rasbian as the OS.  When I run a scan on the computer scanning the Top 20 ports with nmap.  It all comes up with filtered, including the Windows ports.

And when I run a scan, doing a `nmap -v -O 172.16.0.89` it ends immediately.  I've changed my IP address and MAC address.

So I have two questions here, How could it be that all the top 20 ports are filtered while all being windows ports on a Debian-based OS, and how could he still be blocking my virtual machine?

Comment: Do you know what `filtered` means?

Comment: Are you sure the scan is being blocked? Or is the problem on your end? Have you tried `-vvv`?

Comment: Ports don't depend on the OS. You can have any number of ports open or not on any OS. There is just *typical* ports that are used by certain OSes.

Comment: I changed my post, I know what filtered means.  And I am sure it's being blocked, Ill try -vvv when I'm back in class tomorrow

Comment: You could run `ssh` on every port from 1-1024 all at once. And `filtered` doesn't mean `open` ....

Comment: Now I understand that Filtered does not mean open.  I thought that mean that it was activated like open and traffic was filtered through the firewall.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.